# CodeIgniter upload image through tinymce

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, tinymce, codeigniter-2

I'd like some help please. I have created a form with CodeIgniter where I can write posts and what I 'd like to do is to add the functionality to upload image(s) for this post.

At the beginning I thought to add an input field in my form where I can upload files, so I can display them above the content (text) at the front end, but although this is a very quick and easy solution, may be not so flexible. So I thought to use the 'insert/edit image' button that tinymce has.

I haven’t done this before so how can I upload an image or images through tinymce so that they appear within the text at the front-end??

**EDIT** Here is my code.

This is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
<div>
    <label for="title">Title *</label>
    <?php echo form_input('title', html_escape(set_value('title', $article->title))); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="file">Upload image</label>
    <?php echo form_upload('file'); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="body">Body *</label> // has TinyMce
    <?php echo form_textarea('body', strip(set_value('body', $article->body))); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo form_submit('save', 'Save'); ?>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is my model:

```
public function save($id = null){

        $post_data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'file' => $this->input->post('file'),
                'body' => $this->input->post('body'), 
                );

        return parent::save($post_data, $id);
    }
```

This is the controller:

```
public function article($id = null){

        ....

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->article_model->rules);

        // Process the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $this->article_model->save($id);
            redirect('admin/article');
        }
    }
```

Comment: what u have tried so far. Share some code. we can not write complete code for you.

Comment: Sorry forgot that.. please review the post above

Comment: http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/ you can try this TinyMCE plugin. for uploading images or files, it's free for the mean time :)

Comment: This looks quite cool! I'm planing to do some small changes, so what I want to do, basicly, is to upload through a secondary form an image to 'uploads/articles' folder and then in the main form with the tinymce when i click the insert image button to browse the uploads folder and insert the image within the text. Can I do that with this plugin???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

You either keep an upload field outside TinyMCE and use ajax/iframe file upload.

OR

Write a TinyMCE plugin with an ability to upload an image.

Please note that both of these approaches take some effort to implement.

As far as handling the file on the server side is concerned, you can go through the [Codeigniter Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) to get you started.

Comment: you mean to have a plugin that will use the file upload and the image manipulation classes?? how can i do this??

Comment: TinyMCE has it's own way of writing plugins http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.Plugin .You will want one that opens a dialog box, with an upload button and allows the user to choose an image and upload the image. Of course, to handle the uploading itself on the server, you could use image manipulation class offered by codeigniter.

Comment: How can I do this you said? is there any tutorial available or any link that shows how to embed the tinymce's plugin with the codeigniter's image class???

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , I think that you should use separate field to upload images to server as this helps you control them , resize , determine file name and upload path

you can use form_open_multipart() Codeigniter function to upload files

then you can make a DB table field called image and insert the uploaded file name to it

then retrieving the post you can

```
<img src="<?php echo $post->image; ?>" />

<p><?php echo $post->content ?></p>
```

Comment: This is what I decided to do first, but what if in a single post I have more than one images? if I loop through the <img> to display them all, I' ll have a banch of images and then the text, which I don't think that will look nice.

Is there any way to upload an image to the server through tinymce and control them , resize them etc etc through the Image library too??

Comment: I always use the Iframe method to upload files as if they were uploaded by ajax and i think this would be useful for you